# 'Match_view' object has no attribute 'rindex'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, registration

I'm trying to do a simple register form since usercreationform but I obtain this error:

```
File "/home/draicore/project/multilevel/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_mod_func
  143.         dot = callback.rindex('.')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'Match_view' object has no attribute 'rindex'
```

Here my source code:

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,FormView
from .forms import UserForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class Match_view(FormView):
    template_name = 'synopticup/validator.html'
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('vista_validador')
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^dracoin/validator/$',Match_view(),name = 'vista_validador'),
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    pass
```

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `as_view` class method when defining a URL for a class based view.

```
url(r'^dracoin/validator/$',Match_view.as_view(),name = 'vista_validador'),
```